# What distance formula is used in this code and how does it work?

Tags: python, machine-learning

https://www.kaggle.com/code/rxsraghavagrawal/music-genre-classification-using-knn-begineers?scriptVersionId=58136615&cellId=5

```
def distance(instance1, instance2, k):
    distance = 0
    mm1 = instance1[0]
    cm1 = instance1[1]
    mm2 = instance2[0]
    cm2 = instance2[1]
    distance = np.trace(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cm2), cm1))
    distance += (np.dot(np.dot((mm2-mm1).transpose(), np.linalg.inv(cm2)), mm2-mm1))
    distance += np.log(np.linalg.det(cm2)) - np.log(np.linalg.det(cm1))
    distance -= k
    return distance
```

In the distance function defined in the code here, what is formula that is used? I'm having trouble understanding how it is calculating the distance between the two feature vectors.
Also, when the function is called to calculate the distance, why is it called two times and the results are added?

```
for x in range(len(trainingset)):
        dist = distance(trainingset[x], instance, k) + distance(instance,trainingset[x],k)
```

I thought it was the Mahalanobi's formula at first but it's not. So please help me understand this.

Comment: I think it might be the Bhattacharyya distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance

Comment: IMHO, this is not question for SO. i.e. if the code works and there is no programming question here. This is better suited for other StackExchnage sites